# Map JSON for Chartjs with Angular 7

Tags: json, angular, chart.js, bar-chart, angular7

Im trying to map JSON Data to show it in a Bar-Chart. The final Array I need has to look like this:[883, 5925, 17119, 27114, 2758].
Actually, the Array I want to use to set the barChartData (dringlichkeitenValues[])seems to be empty. Sorry for my bad coding skills. Can anyone show me how to solve this Problem?

JSON:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "value": 883
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "value": 5925
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "value": 17119
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "value": 27144
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "value": 2758
}]
```

api.service.ts

```
getDringlichkeiten(): Observable<IDringlichkeit[]> {
    return this.http.get<IDringlichkeit[]>(this.ROOT_URL + '/aufenthalte/dringlichkeit');}
```

dringlichkeit.ts

```
  export interface IDringlichkeit {
  id: number;
  value: number;
}
```

bar-chart.component.ts

```
   export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {

  public dringlichkeitValues:number[] = [];
  public dringlichkeiten: IDringlichkeit[];
  public barChartLabels:String[] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
  public barChartData:number[] = this.dringlichkeitValues;
  public barChartType:string = 'bar';

  constructor(private aufenthaltService: AufenthaltService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadData();
    this.getDringlichkeitValues();
  }

  loadData(){

    this.aufenthaltService.getDringlichkeiten()
    .subscribe( data => this.dringlichkeiten = data);
  }

  getDringlichkeitValues(){
    let dringlichkeitValues:number[]=[];
    this.dringlichkeiten.forEach(dringlichkeit=>{
      dringlichkeitValues.push(dringlichkeit.value)
      this.dringlichkeitValues = dringlichkeitValues;
    });
    return this.dringlichkeitValues;
  }

}
```

**UPDATE:**
I updated my component but now my Array is still empty after subscribing to the Observable.

bar-chart.component.ts

```
chart: Chart;
  dringlichkeiten: IDringlichkeit[] = [];


  constructor(private aufenthaltService: AufenthaltService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.aufenthaltService.getDringlichkeiten()
    .subscribe( data => {
      this.dringlichkeiten = data;

      //dringlichkeiten-Array full
      console.log(this.dringlichkeiten);
    });

    //dringlichkeiten-Array empty
    console.log(this.dringlichkeiten);


    this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: this.dringlichkeiten.map(x => x.id),
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Dringlichkeiten',
            data: this.dringlichkeiten.map(x => x.value),
            backgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#4BC0C0', '#FFCE56', '#E7E9ED', '#36A2EB']
          }
        ]
      },
    });


  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the "values" from your JSON array, you can use:

```
dringlichkeiten.map(x => x.value)
```

This will get you an array you require, i.e.:

```
[883, 5925, 17119, 27114, 2758]
```

You can then pass this array to chartJS for it to render you a chart like so:

```
this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: dringlichkeiten.map(x => x.id),
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'My Bar Chart',
        data: dringlichkeiten.map(x => x.value),
        backgroundColor: ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'orange']
      }
    ]
  },
});
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h83adp-chartjs-ahaqu3) simplified working SlackBlitz example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! Defining the Array in the same Component, like U did, works. But if I want to subscribe to my Observable with loadData() in ngOnInit{} the Array seems still to be empty...When I console.log(this.dringlichkeiten) while I'm subscribing my data is like I need it. Do U know why the local variable dringlichkeiten does not change?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Taking a look at your `ngOnInit` method, I would suggest removing the method `getDringlichkeitValues()` as I don't think it's needed. Is that method what is causing your problem?

Comment: Your method `getDringlichkeitValues()` will run before your `loadData()` method has been resolved as both method are being run `synchronously`, therefore, `this.dringlichkeiten` will always be empty in the `getDringlichkeitValues()` method.

Comment: I removed this method. Could you please check my updated class above? I placed 2 console.logs - 1st one has values, 2nd one doesn't. But why?

Comment: The 2nd `console.log` is empty because it is executed as soon as the component is loaded where as the other is executed once your api call returns the data. You basically need to create the chart AFTER your api call is completed, i.e. once you have the data. Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h83adp-chartjs-hpbk2k) SlackBlitz example, which mimics an api call.